# JQuery return DIVs and their contents only if contains a keyword

Tags: jquery, arrays, filtering

I have serverside output that I have no control of, only the front HTML template - I am using JQuery to manipulate the results for layout purposes.

The concept I am trying to achieve is to seperate Menu items so that some items can appear either at the top of the page in the main nav or at the bottom of the page as they are less important visually.

To identify items for the top menu I am using a token (for now lets say this is the constant value: TOP ) and I was hoping to have some jquery scan each node and isolate each item depending on this token. So each TOP xxx element will collect to form the top menu and anything else collect to form the bottom menu.

Here's an example of the output I have to deal with below, my goal would be for Menu Items 1 and 3 to become a html structure I can pass into a div with id=TOPMENU and #2 to be dropped into div id=BOTTOMMENU.

Please note: I wish to retain the H3 and the outer menuElement div structure.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Hope you can help.

```
<div id="menusHolder">
  <div class="menuElement">
     <h3>TOP Menu Title 1</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuElement">
     <h3>Menu Title 2</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuElement">
     <h3>TOP Menu Title 3</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
var topElements = $("#menusHolder .menuElement h3:contains('TOP')").parent();
var bottomElements = $("#menusHolder .menuElement").not(topElements);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HRs8N/

Comment: Hi pfyod thanks for your help this is what I needed.@Daniel - thanks also for your help and if I did have access to the rendered HTML that is a solution I would have used so thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Hi pfoyd as an extension of this question could you assist with the next part of the problem? I have posted it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810944/appending-jquery-array-elements-to-matching-list-nodes#

Answer (score 0):

A better way to go about this would be to use a class as that's exactly what they're make for, to classify things. If you have the flexibility to add a token to the HTML you should have the flexibility to add a class also.

Messing around with text inside HTML elements tends to be messy, for example it could break if any menu item contained the text "TOP" and it's also more work to get those elements than to simply get all elements of a particular class.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/MRppH/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="menusHolder">
  <div class="menuElement top">
     <h3>Menu Title 1</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuElement">
     <h3>Menu Title 2</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuElement top">
     <h3>Menu Title 3</h3>
     <ul>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.top').each(function () {
        // Do something with $(this)
    });
});
```

Comment: He says that he cannot control HTML output so he cannot add class to those menu items. If he can do it, selecting by class is obviously better than by content.

Comment: hi thanks for your input so far daniel and pfyod, to clarify the token in the h3 tag TOP comes from a value entered in the cms and was the only mechanism i could conceive to provide a distinguishment between items