# Appending Jquery array elements to matching List Nodes

Tags: jquery, arrays, filtering

as an extension to this problem:
[JQuery return DIVs and their contents only if contains a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809376/jquery-return-divs-and-their-contents-only-if-contains-a-keyword)

My menu has been split into 2 components now - Top menu elements and bottom menu elements based on a token value in the html (for now this is TOP )

The next issue is the top menu div already contains static code as shown below - how would it be possible to match the newly created items (for the top menu) to their matching static structure. Let me show you the html:

STATIC HTML

```
<div id="top">
    <ul>
        <li>Category 1</li>
        <li>Category 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each item in this 'topelement' consists of a surrounding div containing a h3 tag and a following UL with list items.

As an example: The first h3 tag would contain the text 'TOP Item 1' indicating its to be put in the topElement group and my goal is to isolate the string 'TOP ' and marry the 'Item 1' UL that follows to the List item in the static nav so this becomes a sub nav element as follows:

```
<div id="top">
    <ul>
        <li>Category 1
            <ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>
        </li>
        <li>Category 3<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Mrfitz, you want to transform the structure as above mentioned right ?

Comment: hi, yes I have defined the top structure manually in my html - I then have some jquery which can be seen on the above link which filters some data and produces a filtered list called topElement. I now need that new list of results transformed onto the static structure above.

you can see on this fiddle the data I am left with and need to use this to create the sub nested List items

http://jsfiddle.net/HRs8N/

Comment: Hi MrFitz: I Have done the necessary modification to your code, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/HRs8N/6/ . Happy coding

Comment: thats brillient thanks for your help!

Comment: MrFitz :if you have found the answer can u close the question by ticking against the answer,this would reduce the number of open questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi MrFitz: I Have done the necessary modification to your code, here is the link

jsfiddle.net/HRs8N/6 .

Happy coding :)